# iOS and Google Nearby API: how to publish and subscribe in the right way?

Tags: ios, google-nearby

I've done as [the guide says](https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/ios/pub-sub)

This is the message manager

```
[GNSMessageManager setDebugLoggingEnabled:YES];
messageManager = [[GNSMessageManager alloc] initWithAPIKey:API_KEY paramsBlock:^(GNSMessageManagerParams *params) {
        params.bluetoothPowerErrorHandler = ^(BOOL hasError) {
            // Update the UI for Bluetooth power
        };
        params.bluetoothPermissionErrorHandler = ^(BOOL hasError) {
            // Update the UI for Bluetooth permission
        };
    }];
```

These are my methods to publish and subscribe with the Nearby API.

```
- (IBAction)onPublish:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"publish");
    NSString* str = @"hello world";
    NSData* data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    GNSMessage* message = [GNSMessage messageWithContent:data];
    id<GNSPublication> publication = [messageManager publicationWithMessage:message paramsBlock:^(GNSPublicationParams *publicationParams) {
        publicationParams.strategy = [GNSStrategy strategyWithParamsBlock:^(GNSStrategyParams * strategyParams) {
            strategyParams.allowInBackground = YES;
            strategyParams.discoveryMediums = kGNSDiscoveryMediumsBLE;
            strategyParams.discoveryMode = kGNSDiscoveryModeDefault;
        }];;
    }];
}

- (IBAction)onSubscribe:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"subscribe");
    id<GNSSubscription> subscription = [messageManager subscriptionWithMessageFoundHandler:^(GNSMessage *msg) {
        // Add the name to a list for display
        NSLog(@"message found %@", [msg description]);
    } messageLostHandler:^(GNSMessage *msg) {
        // Add the name to a list for display
        NSLog(@"message lost %@", [msg description]);
    } paramsBlock:^(GNSSubscriptionParams *subscriptionParams) {
        subscriptionParams.strategy = [GNSStrategy strategyWithParamsBlock:^(GNSStrategyParams * strategyParams) {
            strategyParams.allowInBackground = YES;
            strategyParams.discoveryMediums = kGNSDiscoveryMediumsBLE;
            strategyParams.discoveryMode = kGNSDiscoveryModeDefault;
        }];;
    }];
}
```

Both Bletooth central and peripheral background capabilities are enabled, and the permission string for the peripheral is set.
Finally I subscribe on an iOS device and publish from another one but nothing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure to retain the publication and subscription objects.  They stop publishing/subscribing when they're deallocated.  The usual way is to store them as properties/ivars in one of your classes.

The developer docs are misleading on this point, and I apologize.  We'll improve the docs in the next release.